# Why is my Arch Linux VM not saving after a reboot?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, arch-linux

I'm trying to set up my own Arch Linux install on a virtual machine, but I've found out that every time I reboot the VM it loses all my content. I think this is because I'm using a live ISO for Arch, but I don't know how to transition from using the live image to having a properly installed machine. I know this is a dumb question, but I'm new to VM. I have other VMs (debian, ubuntu) that save all my stuff just fine when restarting. I know this is a dumb question, but any advice would be appreciated.

NOTE: This happens regardless of how I shut it off, whether it be sending the shutoff signal, restarting the machine, or rebooting from Arch itself. I can save the machine state just fine though.

Comment: Two things:  Live ISOs are  NOT persistent,  secondly,  have you set the save state option in whatever VM tool you are using?   Generally using the text or gui installer not just the live environment will make it a properly installed instance which should save its state (short of the usual culprits like a emergency shutdown,  power fail,etc)

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I ended up figuring out. I had to remove the ISO as Vbox had the boot order set to use the ISO before the hard drive. I also had to set my drives to automount into the right directory, as the changes I was making weren't actually changing on the drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your live Arch is being held virtually on your hard drive, it won't remain there until you have a proper install, virtual is basically a mirror image of the live operating system and is held by virtual memory which is also a temporary partition on your hard drive.
There's usually a install link on your list of programs/ apps on your desktop to install or a choice is given when booting your arch Linux.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to figure out where that install link might be. I've gotten as far as to set up my drive partiioning, userspace, install a bootloader etc but no matter what I do it always goes away the next time I boot.. I guess a better question would be, how do I install Arch Linux?